# Text Parsing Design

Tags: python, nlp

Let's say I have a paragraph of text like so:

> *Snails **can*** be found in a very wide
>   range of environments including
>   ditches, deserts, and the abyssal
>   depths of the sea. Numerous kinds of *snail **can***
>   also be found in fresh waters. [(source)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_snail)

I have 10,000 regex rules to match text, which can overlap. For example, the regex `/Snails? can/i` will find two matches (italicized in the text). The regex `/can( also)? be/i` has two matches (bolded).

After iterating through my regexes and finding matches, what is the best data structure to use, that given some place in the text, it returns all regexes that mached it? For example, if I want the matches for line 1, character 8 (0-based, which is the `a` in `can`), I would get a match for both regexes previously described.

I can create a hashmap: (key: character location, value: set of all matching regexes). Is this optimal? Is there a better way to parse the text with thousands of regexes (to not loop through each one)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you comment on the more general use of this? How will you be taking advantage of the data you're wishing to store?

Comment: The user sees the parsed text, highlighted with matching regexes. When the users hovers over a character, matching regexes are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing all of the matches in a dictionary will work, but will it means you'll have to store all of the matches in memory at the same time. If your data is small enough to easily fit into memory, don't worry about it. Just do what works and move on.

If you do need to reduce memory usage of increase speed it really depends on how you are using the data. For example, if you process positions starting at the beginning and going to the end, you could use re.finditer to iteratively process all of the regexes and not maintain extra matches in memory longer then needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your regex does not cross between multiple sentences. In that case you could

```
1) break your text into array of sentences
2) for each sentence simply record which (id) regex have matched.
3) when you would like to see the match - run the regex again.
```

"Store less / compute more" solution.

Comment: Sorry if I conveyed that the regex can't cross sentences. It can. Interesting solution.

Comment: Then IMO your hashmap approach is rather optimal. Make sure your "value" is searchable, so you can query for things like "where does regex ### match?"

Comment: i agree, hash is probably your best bet

Comment: Actually an inverse hash would be better: key(regex id), value(character position / char count).